# Numpy Not Allowing Use of Python 'Sum' Function?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, pyqt

I just installed Pylab and Matplotlib to create a graph that is all working fine. Then I went to open another python file for my program and noticed an error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\fromnumeric.py", line 1708, in sum
    sum = a.sum
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'sum'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\JD\git\ComputingCoursework\Coursework\Implementation\Files\AddDataGUI.py", line 768, in <module>
    launcher = AddDataWindow('Hardware')
  File "C:\Users\JD\git\ComputingCoursework\Coursework\Implementation\Files\AddDataGUI.py", line 33, in __init__
    self.col = sum([[i,''] for i in self.col],[])   ## adds a space in between each item in self.col tuple
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\fromnumeric.py", line 1711, in sum
    out=out, keepdims=keepdims)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\_methods.py", line 32, in _sum
    return umr_sum(a, axis, dtype, out, keepdims)
TypeError: cannot perform reduce with flexible type
```

Here is the code that seems to be causing an error

```
self.col = sum([[i,''] for i in self.col],[])
```

It has been workig fine before numpy was installed? HELP!

Comment: Never use `from pylab import *` or `from numpy import *` since these imports would **overwrite** the builtin definition of `sum` with NumPy's `sum` function. Use of one of these imports might be the cause of the problem you are seeing. Instead use `import numpy as np` so you can control access to NumPy functions explicitly (e.g. with `np.sum`).

Comment: Yes, check your imports. Try `print sum.__module__`. If that says `numpy.core.fromnumeric`, your `sum` is actually `numpy.sum`

Comment: I have no pylab imports in this file? Would it still affect the file if there was an from pylab import * in another file?

Comment: FIXED: Thank you very much! It turns out I had imported the file that has the import * with it! Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

You can typically find the original python `sum` at:

```
__builtin__.sum
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply :) Fixed it as shown in comments

Answer (score 1):

Never use `from pylab import *` or `from numpy import *` since these imports would overwrite the builtin definition of sum with NumPy's sum function. Use of one of these imports might be the cause of the problem you are seeing. Instead use `import numpy as np` so you can control access to NumPy functions explicitly (e.g. with `np.sum`).

Other reasons to avoid using `from module import *` in general are that it pollutes the global namespace and makes it harder to trace where variables have been defined.